# Creating dynamic divider to match flex-wrap state

Tags: html, css

I need to add a vertical divider between the two squares and change it to a horizontal divider if the items are flex-wrapped on resize. I have tried using `before` & `after` but couldn't find a solution for changing the dimensions of the divider to match the state of the flex-wrap.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid
}

.box * {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item:last-child {
  background: red;
}

.item:first-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using grid? You can set cols based on breakpoints and style it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then for the css:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box-wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(1, 1, 1);
}

.box-wrapper:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .box-wrapper {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right: none;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .box-wrapper:first-child {
    border-top: none;
  }
}

.item {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I need the dividing lines to switch to horizontal when flex-wrapped. These stay vertical.

Comment: You have the horizontal lines when every box is wrapped;  view the code with window smaller than 500px. you can modify that media query as you wish.